# Perimeter of the circle on a complex vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a complex vector space of dimension $1$.
Let $||.||$ be a norm on $V$ and let us note $C_R$ the circle of center $0$ and radius $R$ associated to this norm. ($R>0.$)
Let $dz$ be a Haar measure on $V$.

Are we sure that $$\int_{C_R} dz = cR$$ for some real constant $c$ (which does not depend on $R$) ?

Comment: There is only one norm (up to a constant  factor) in a one dimendional vector space and Haar measure is (up to a constant  factor) same as Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Haar measure on $V$ is $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure (up to a constant), curve $C_R$ has $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure zero, so that integral is zero.

Comment: I do not mean the $dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ but simply $dz$. (Like usual curvilign integrals on $\mathbb{C}$) Perhaps Haar measure is not the good word.